# Quite confused with Fourier Analysis results

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft, continuous-signals

So I'm meant to show how the DFT can find the frequencies, and respective amplitudes, associated to some data. And I have this data set from the curve
$$
f(t) = 1 + 2\cos(2\pi t) + 4\cos(4\pi t)
$$
sampled with a period $T_s = 0.1$ gives the following between 0 and 1,
[7.00, 3.85,-1.62,-2.85,0.62, 3.00,0.62, -2.85,-1.62,3.85]
and using the simple Scipy fft library it gives,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1.00000000\cdot 10^{1}+0.j\\   9.98643159+0.j \\  1.99952239\cdot 10^1 +0.j \\
   1.35684102\cdot 10^{-2} +0.j\\   4.77614058 \cdot 10^{-3}+0.j\\   0.00000000 +0.j\\
   4.77614058\cdot 10^{-3}-0.j\\   1.35684102 \cdot 10^{-2}-0.j\\   1.99952239 \cdot 10^{1}-0.j\\
   9.98643159 -0.j\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My instructor has said that each frequency should be multiplied by two and the upper limit, in this case, would be $\mathcal{F}[4]$ however I'm still not sure where this comes from. Was hoping someone could explain this to me thank you.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the `e` in your output! `1.2e3` means $1.2\cdot 10^3= 1200$, not $1.2e^3\approx 24$.

Comment: also, from a quick look: the fifth and the seventh coefficient must be the same. My guess: you meant $e-3$ and wrote $e3$ instead in the fifth.

Comment: Also, try with a vector length of 8 instead of 10.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Uh no? $\mathcal{F}[n]/10$ is 1 which is what is expected, but $9.98/10 \neq 2$ and $20.0/10 \neq 4$ this is what I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. To what are you saying "no"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are right for the second part though just a typo.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know what e^x means...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying "no" to. Please explain.
I also don't understand where your formula "9.98/10" comes from. Can you elaborate? Why are you expecting that to be 2?

Comment: If you know what e^x means, why are you then giving us numbers as factors in front of e^x ? (Still not quite sure you really mean what you write.)

Comment: Since to normalise the fft you divide by $n$, which is 10, therefore the amplitude of a frequency of 1, from the curve $f(t) = 1 + 2\cos(2\pi t) + 4\cos(4\pi t)$, should be 2 not 1.

Comment: no, it should not. Why should it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I assumed the fft gave you the amplitudes of the frequencies after normalisation no?

Comment: Yes, but only for tones at the exact frequencies of the DFT bins. That's why I said "try with a length of 8".

Comment: @MarcusMüller As for the e notation, (10^x), it's just what scipy outputs and I'm not going to go back and edit every single output when its fairly self-explanatory..

Comment: Okay now I understand it must be done in powers of 2, I just assumed that it would use a bin of 16 and set the others to 0 but okay.

Comment: "I'm not going back and do a trivial edit to make things correct" also means that I will not be coming back to this discussion, if that's the amount of work you're putting in. And no, it doesn't have to be done in powers of two. That's not the point. I gave you the point in my previous comment. Have a nice day!

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with $e^{01}$ it is common scientific notations?

Answer (score 0):

You have a programming problem somewhere. Below I show you a very simple Matlab / Octave implementation of what you are after:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

Ts = 0.1;           % Sampling period
N = 10;             % number fo samples to take
t = Ts*(0:N-1)';    % sampling time points from t0=0 to tN-1 = Ts*(N-1) 

f = 1 + 2*cos(2*pi*t) + 4*cos(4*pi*t)      % f(t) sampled at Fs=1/Ts
F = fft(f,N)      % N-point DFT/FFT of f(t)
```

And the output, at the Matlab console, of this simple computation is the following:

```
f =

    7.0000
    3.8541
   -1.6180
   -2.8541
    0.6180
    3.0000
    0.6180
   -2.8541
   -1.6180
    3.8541

F =

  10.0000          
  10.0000 - 0.0000i
  20.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.0000          
   0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  20.0000 + 0.0000i
  10.0000 + 0.0000i
```

As can be seen, the DFT $F[k]$ output is as expected. Note that the first DFT bin (k=0) $F[0] = 10$ is the $N \times $ the DC value of x[n]. Also, the DFT bins for $k=1,2,8,9$ (or the F vector elements at indices 2,3,9,10) correspond to those two cosine waves. Sepcifically bins 1 and 9 , and , bins 2 and 8 correspond to first and second cosine terms respectively.

This means that you have a programming error. To find where it is, first check that your time domain samples of f[n] are the same as those of f(t) printed above. If they are not the same, then your sampling stage has a problem. Most probably you have an issue in generating the sampling times. If the time domain sample values are the same as above then your DFT/FFT stage is doing something wrong. But that's a very weak probability.

Comment: But I get the same results as you? But it's fine i understand why the values are doubled.

Comment: @JohnMiller they ar not the same. Look at your data, for example first three bins: F(0) = 10.0, F(1) = 9.98 , F(2) = 19.99 . Wheres data in my post is: F(0)=10.0, F(1)=10.0, F(2)=20.0 . So they are very close but not the same and the correct one is the second set.

Comment: It's just because I sample my data to 3 significant figures not more.

Comment: oh I see it now! But your FFT results are not correct to any figures, interesting  :-P ...